Movie about Hercules or similar kind of hero and witch
I have watched an American movie when I was little (between 2000 and 2006, I don't think it was new at that time) and I need to know what it was. I remember a few scenes from it. This film could probably be about Hercules although I am not 100% sure.

I remember a scene was there about an old witch and she drinks from the hero's blood and became young again.
Another scene was when he had to retrieve an object protected by a layer of ice and a layer of fire and he had to put his arm through them.
In another scene there was an old roman gladiator horse carriage that was in a tower or room and the witch created a rope that the hero tied to a rock an then threw it and they flew in that carriage. On their path the rope got cut and it was because the witch fell in love with him and lost her magic.

Any idea what that film was?

Welcome to Movies & TV! When did you see this? How old was it? What country was it set/made in? What language was it in? Can you describe any of the cast, name any of the actors? Please try to provide some more detail, otherwise I'm afraid this question is likely to be put on hold.

i am sorry i dot not remember the cast a watched it between 2000 and 2006 but i dont think it was new at that time it was an american movie

You are describing Hercules from 1983 with Lou Ferrigno. It contains all the scene you've described:

Hercules comes across an old witch (Circe) who drinks his blood and becomes young again;
Hercules has to plunge his hand through a barrier of fire and then ice to retrieve a talisman;
Hercules ties a rock to a chariot and throws the rock, allowing him and Circe to fly back to Earth, but the rope breaks because Circe fell in love with Hercules and lost her powers.

Followed by a sequel in 1985. Here's the trailer (where you can briefly see the chariot scene):




Yes that is the one. Thank you @Walt
